# Graphing 3D function

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d

How would I hand-graph a region that is bounded by $z = 6 - 2 x^2/3, x = y^2$, and the $xy$-plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $y$ and $z$ as a function of the single variable $x$, i.e.,

$y(x) = \sqrt{x}$

$z(x) = 6 - \frac{2 x^2}{3}$

and then compute three-dimensional coordinates $\{ x, y(x), z(x) \}$ for a range of $x$.

If you're working in the stone age and need to do this by hand, make a table with values of $x$, $y$, $z$ and plot them in three dimensions and connect them by a smooth curve.

But why oh why do this *by hand*?!

[image]

Comment: It's for my multivariable calculus class, David. :( Thank you for your help, but I really need to know how to do this by hand.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by putting x and y as a function of the single variable?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.